# Enabling Cloudwatch cross-account functionality via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm looking forward enabling the cross-account cross-region account selector in cloudwatch via terraform.

It is called "Enable account switching" in the console.

I can't find any related resources in the terraform documentation.

Comment: I think this is not possible yet, but also interested in this.